# C - strange size_t error when generating files with rpcgen

Tags: c, linux, linked-list, rpc, size-t

I'm new in rpcgen and my knowledge in C is not the best. For my project I need to use linked lists because many functions will retrieve a list of data from a database to a client. I have already implemented and generated a code "lista.h" and "lista.c" with the definitions of the functions and the structures of the list and the code of the functions respectively.

In "Linkder.x" (Linkder is the name of my application) I have defined everything necessary to generate the files and included "lista.h".

The problem is when I generate the files with rpcgen applying the command `rpcgen -C -a Linkder.x`, gives me the following error:

`typedef long unsigned int size_t;
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/include/stddef.h, line 216: expected '*' or 'identifier'`

When I open stddef.h with a text editor, line 216 shows this:
[stddef.h](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wHcfp.png)

I don't know what is generating this error. I have tested my list creating a test.c file and compiles and runs fine. Maybe this error is caused by the sizeof operator when I use the malloc function to create a new node.

The only thing that fix the error is deleting the #include "lista.h" and every function that use the list in my .x file.

Here is my code:

```
/*Linkder.x*/
#include "estructuras.h"
#include "lista.h"

program Linkder {
    version LINKDER_VER {
        /*Funciones*/

        tlista *listar_juegos() = 1;

        tlista *recomendar_juegos() = 2;

        void crear_usuario(struct usuario) = 4; 

        void juego_fav(struct datos_juego) = 5; 

        void borrar_juego(struct datos_juego) = 6;

        tlista *obtener_usuario_juego(int) = 7;

        tlista *obtener_juegos_fav(char[50]) = 8;

        void login(struct usuario) = 9;
    } = 1;
} = 1;
```

lista.h:

```
/*lista.h*/
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


typedef struct nodo {
    char nombre_juego[50];
    char nick_jugador[50];
    int id_juego;
    struct nodo *next;
} tnodo;

typedef struct {
    tnodo *head;
    int size;
} tlista;


/*funciones*/
//void delete(tlista *l);

int getsize(tlista l);

int isempty(tlista l);

void insert(tlista *l, char c1[50], char c2[50], int num);

/*void view(tlista l);*/

void create(tlista *l);
```

lista.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "string.h"
#include "lista.h"

int getsize(tlista l) {
    return(l.size);
}        

int isempty(tlista l) {
    if(l.size == 0) {
        return(1);
    } else {
        return(0);
    }
}

void insert(tlista *l, char c1[50], char c2[50], int num) {
    tnodo *aux;
    if(isempty(*l)) {
        l->head = (tnodo*)malloc(sizeof(tnodo));
        strcpy(l->head->nombre_juego, c1);
        strcpy(l->head->nick_jugador, c2);
        l->head->id_juego = num;
        l->head->next = NULL;
        l->size++;                
    } else {
        aux = l->head;
        while(aux->next != NULL)
        {
            aux = aux->next;
        }
        aux->next = (tnodo*)malloc(sizeof(tnodo));
        strcpy(aux->next->nombre_juego, c1);
        strcpy(aux->next->nick_jugador, c2);
        aux->next->id_juego = num;
        aux->next->next = NULL;
        l->size++; 
    }
}

void create(tlista *l)
{
     l->head=NULL;
     l->size=0;
}
```

rpcgen version is 2.27, gcc version is 7.5.0. My OS is Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS
I have tested my code on different PCs

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `#include "string.h"` is somewhat suspicious.  I would expect `#include <string.h>`

Comment: Are you sure there's no more to the error message?

Comment: @ChristianGibbons i changed it and doesn't work :(

Comment: @bk2204 the rpc compiler only gives me that error

Comment: Not an expert on this, but it looks like the point is that the .x file is not truly C, although it resembles it, and only supports a subset of what C might provide.  As such you should not try to include any standard C headers into your .x file.

Comment: @NateEldredge Indeed, according to Rpc programming guide: "rpcgen is  a  compiler.  It accepts  a  remote  program  interface  definition  written  in  a  language,  called  RPCLanguage, which is similar to C". And according to wikipedia the types supported are: "Constant, Enumeration, Struct, Union, Typedef and Program". This is weird because the linked list implementation is a struct with another struct inside. I didn't know that I can't use any C standard library. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This answer suggests that unsigned long long isn't defined when you are using rpcgen.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/43186591/10273360

I don't actually know how to evade this error, but I can tell you that the error is coming because you have included the `stdio.h and stdlib.h` header files, which in turn are including stddef.h inside your own lista.h header file.

> `#include <stdio.h>`
>   `#include <stdlib.h>`

And it also happens that you can remove both of these without any problems, as your header file doesn't use any functions coming from these two headers.

The solution to the above problem ends here. But the program still fails compilation for other errors. I'd suggest maybe try solving it yourself, or open another thread for that.

This isn't a like a proper solution or an explanation, but this is what I can tell. More like a pseudo solution. I am not really experienced with rpcgen and it would be great if anyone more experienced can shed some light here.

Comment: I can't remove <stdlib.h> because cause problems with typedef. I think the only solution is use an array of structs to save de data from the database and send it to the client. Thanks.

Comment: stdlib.h isn't needed for typedef, there's some other problem here. I solved the typedef issue by expanding the statement (still keeping the same behavior). For example - https://pastebin.com/A0RGjZq4